# php.ini says it's being read, but any customizations don't appear

Tags: php, apache

I'm running PHP7.4 on an EC2 instance running Ubuntu / Apache2. After doing some updates (just with apt-get update, upgrade, etc.) my php appears to be screwed up. Everything is currently set to the default configuration. Modules can be loaded but any customizations to php.ini will not take effect.

Just to be clear, I've run `phpinfo()` in my web browser and it says the php.ini file loaded is:

```
/etc/php/7.4/apache2/php.ini
```

In this file, I have `memory_limit = 3048M`. I've restarted and reloaded apache multiple times. No matter what, `phpinfo()` always says that my `memory_limit` is 128M. `memory_limit` isn't the only thing, `max_input_vars`, `max_input_time`, any variable inside of the "loaded" php.ini file is not being loaded.

What could the issue be?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Apache wasn't warning me of any errors in my php.ini file. I went to `/var/log/apache2/error.log` and found the syntax error in my php.ini file.